# OkHttpClient.Builder sslSocketFactory is deprecated

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to make https calls  using (retrofit 2.0, okhttp3) I have already included ssl certificate and it works fine with
`OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
 builder.sslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig());`
   but it shows sslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig()) as deprecated and provides other option
`sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager)`
I wanted to update my code and use new option instead of deprecated method
I searched on net but could not find any good reference. If any one can provide some good reference to this issue will be very helpful